# NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id , selenium test for looping WebElements

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to loop through the selector for multiple elements and getting invalid session after the first element.

```
await container.findElements(By.css('.sfsdff')).then((elements) => {
    if (elements.length !== 0) {
      elements.forEach((data) => {
        data.getText().then((data1) => {
          console.log(data1);
        }, err => console.error(`error: ${err}`));
      });
    } 
  });
```

`elements` has exact count that the selector meant to get from the page, its just the loop that the next elements are unable to process after first.

Thanks

Comment: what is this element and what is the state of the webapp when you are looping through it

Comment: elements is list of `WebElement` of type `span` , Webpage is active no change .. its part of the automation scripts

Comment: means is it abutton UI , please add more details

Comment: Its not a UI button , a list of spans and trying to get the text of those spans.